# How can I search the commit history with git?

Tags: git

When I merge code, there may be conflicts in my code:

[image]

How can I, only with the `git` command (without using github or gitlab), search the commit history for the commit with the ID in question?

Answer (score 3):

In the merge conflicts from your code

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        if (value.length < 2) {
=======
        if (!value.length) {
>>>>>>> 1cb09860a286222389dafafb372ae66d85f74f40
```

the SHA-1 hash `1cb09860a286222389dafafb372ae66d85f74f40` is the ID from the commit which is being merged *into* your branch from the other branch.

If you want to view the information for this commit, you can use `git show`:

```
git show 1cb0986
```